# merging excel files into 1 with same column name

Tags: c#

I have the following error...

```
System.Data.DuplicateNameException: 'A column named 'samplex' already     
belongs to this DataTable.'
```

I have large multiple excel files that need merging into one. But all the column names are the same. So I think that is why I am getting this error.

All the data is in sheet1 one from each excel files. Searching on the net the best one I found was using Spire.Xls, sample taken from [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a08113/solutions-to-merge-multiple-excel-worksheets-into-one/)

My code sample, using console...

```
using Spire.Xls;
    ::
    ::
        Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
        workbook.LoadFromFile(@"filea.xlsx");

        Workbook workbook2 = new Workbook();
        workbook2.LoadFromFile(@"fileb.xlsx");

        Workbook workbook3 = new Workbook();
        workbook3.LoadFromFile(@"filec.xlsx");

        Worksheet sheet2 = workbook3.Worksheets[0];
        DataTable dataTable = sheet2.ExportDataTable();
        Worksheet sheet1 = workbook.Worksheets[0];
        sheet1.InsertDataTable(dataTable, false, sheet1.LastRow + 1, 1);


        //save the workbook
        workbook.SaveToFile("result.xlsx");
```

Appreciate if anyone can help me on this?

Comment: doesn't `ExportDataTable` have a noHeader parameter? https://www.e-iceblue.com/forum/worksheet-exportdatatable-malfunction-t4781.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I used Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, sample taken from [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a08113/solutions-to-merge-multiple-excel-worksheets-into-one/), it solve the problem regarding columns with same name. The code is long and complicated but it works but you will need Microsoft Office on the machine. Only a slight problem is that the results shows in new sheet, it doesn't go directly into sheet1. If anyone can advise me on this, it will be ideal.

I am using Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're able to get `DataTable` objects and all the column names are the same, I'd bet you could use `DataTable.Merge()` -

```
Workbook workbook1 = ...;
Workbook workbook2 = ...;

DataTable bookTable1 = workbook1.ExportDataTable();
DataTable booktable2 = workbook2.ExportDataTable();

bookTable1.Merge(bookTable2);

// Spire specific API calls to save bookTable1 to Excel file
```

The only requirement for your data is that you have a key column. [To configure the `DataTable` with a key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/defining-primary-keys) -

```
bookTable1.PrimaryKey = bookTable1.Columns("DataID" /* your key column name here */);
```

Comment: the issue seems to be that ExportDataTable fails because DataTable doesn't allow duplicate column names.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CellRange.Copy(CellRange destRange) method in Spire.XLS to merge worksheets from different workbooks into one, it won't throw the DuplicateNameException.

Refer to the following code:

```
//Load the first workbook
        Workbook workbook1 = new Workbook();
        workbook1.LoadFromFile("Sample.xlsx");

        Worksheet sheet1 = workbook1.Worksheets[0];

        //Load the second workbook
        Workbook workbook2 = new Workbook();
        workbook2.LoadFromFile("sample2.xlsx");

        Worksheet sheet2 = workbook2.Worksheets[0];

        int a = sheet2.LastRow;
        int b = sheet2.LastColumn;

        //Copy data from the 2nd row in sheet2 into sheet1
        sheet2.Range[2, 1, a, b].Copy(sheet1.Range[sheet1.LastRow + 1, 1, a + sheet1.LastRow, b]);            

        workbook1.SaveToFile("reslut.xlsx", ExcelVersion.Version2013);
```

I have already tried the code and it works well on my side.